# How to use the source() function to launch a R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use the `source` function with a R Shiny app.
I tried something similar as the following code but it does not lauch the Shiny app

```r
# This code runs but does not launch my Shiny app
source("path/to/my/Shiny_app.R")

# Or
source("path/to/my/Shiny_app.R", local = T)
```

Something I am missing ?

Comment: Use `shiny::runApp(appDir = "path/to/my/Shiny_app.R")` to launch app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function `runApp` from `shiny` package to launch app:

```
shiny::runApp(appDir = "path/to/my/Shiny_app.R")
```